# Horizontal ellipsis shown by its named entity in question blurb

Tags: bug, status-completed

Most likely there is some tinkering going on, but where there should be an ellipsis there is the following `&hellip;` which I figured stands for horizontal ellipsis?

[image: Bug with ellipsis]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deployment bug. Now fixed. Sorry about that.